# Elixir immutability in a game context

Tags: memory-management, elixir, immutability

I'm aware that, in order to ensure that all threads reading a memory access read the exact same value, Elixir never overwrites an address in use. Instead, if a var is changed, it's written in a new address.

What I want to know is how that would affect real time games. For instance, moving in a 3D game would generate a huge number of different values needing to be newly allocated and the old values to be released in a timely manner. How better or worse is this, for a game, compared to simply rewriting the values in memory as needed?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very generic question. Like *very* generic.

The first and foremost, BEAM (Elixir and Erlang VM) is prioritizing throughput and predictable responsiveness over latency, but in the games the latency is a king, more latency you have, less FPS there will be.

Second, BEAM was designed primarily for fault-tolerance and concurrency not performance, so performance-wise C/C++ will be faster on doing direct memory access and computations.

In general, there are advantages in immutable data structures (safe concurrency, simpler reasoning about programs, less headache during debugging and simpler algorithms in general: i.e. it is much easier construct new RB tree than implement concurrent deletion from it) at cost of raw performance.